# Can we convert "ANDROID OS APP" (.apk) to "CHROME OS APP"?

Tags: android, apk, google-chrome-os

I don't know this is possible or not but we need to convert "ANDROID OS APP" (.apk) to "CHROME OS APP". Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can! Use Arc Welder.

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc

The App Runtime for Chrome (Beta), or ARC, lets you run your favorite Android apps on Chrome OS. By following these steps, you can try out the App Runtime for Chrome (Beta) during this Developer Preview.

To test your app, you need three things:

1. Your APK.
2. PC, Mac, Linux, or Chromebook on Chrome Version 41+.
   Note: ARC is no longer supported on 32-bit x86 platforms and those platforms will no longer receive updates after October 13, 2015. All ARM platforms will continue to work and receive updates.
3. The ARC Welder app.

Comment: in fact, some heavy applications, like Hearthstone, are not currently supported, but they're working on it. I hope :)

Comment: Thank you Nick.. I have tablet device with CHROME OS and I need to convert my android tablet app to it.. I will check and get back to you.